# Cannot set custom width for ngx smart modal

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular6

I am trying to set custom width in ngx-smart-modal.

I have tried steps given on ([How to add unique custom CSS to ngx-smart-modals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150480/how-to-add-unique-custom-css-to-ngx-smart-modals)) and also tried solution for issues created for this project on github but no luck :(.

version "ngx-smart-modal": "^7.1.1",

in global styles.scss i imported

`@import '~ngx-lightbox/lightbox.css';`

`@import "~ngx-smart-modal/ngx-smart-modal";`

in component .html

```
<ngx-smart-modal [customClass]="'pack-modal-custom'" #packModal identifier="packModal" class="pack-modal">
  <p>
     love this game
  </p>
</ngx-smart-modal>
```

in component .scss

```
.pack-modal-custom{
  min-width: 800px !important;
  max-width: none !important;
  background-color: black !important;
 }
```

But still the width of this modal is coming 520px which is set in .nsm-dialog. 
Is there anything i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solutnion 1:**

Change the component's `encapsulation` to `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native`

```
@Component({
  selector: ...,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
  ...
})
```

**Solutnion 2:**

```
::ng-deep .pack-modal-custom{
  min-width: 800px !important;
  max-width: none !important;
  background-color: black !important;
 }
```

**Solutnion 3:**

Move your `.pack-modal-custom` sass code to a global .scss file (e.g. styles.scss in root folder)

**Explenation:**

You need to understand angular's component css mechanize first. Lets make long story short, when adding style to the component's .scss file, angular is generating a *token* that is responsible for adding the style to the component's elements only. This is the reason that you wont get your sass code affecting nxg-modal. In order to do that you'll need to change the component's encapsulation mode. Or add `::ng-deep` which is "pushing" the style to a global style tag for you. Or you'll do it yourself by adding it to a global sass file.

Check this [angular guild](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles) for more details.

Comment: thanks. It's working. But using ::ng-deep i can't set the border radius property. any idea why?

Comment: If you'll make some example demo with this problem I could help. Without it I can't really tell what is the problem, sorry.